# Defining the loudness in terms of mass and time

Tags: mass, acoustics, time, dimensional-analysis, intensity

The unit of loudness is $$\rm\frac{W}{m^2},$$ which is equivalent to $$\rm\frac{kg}{s^3}.$$ Since kg is the SI unit for mass and s is the SI unit for time, this led me to the following question:

Can the loudness be defined as the mass of a body divided by the cube of time?

Comment: The unit of loudness is **not** $\frac{W}{m^{2}}$. This is indeed the unit of intensity but loudness is **not** the same as the intensity. The unit of loudness is defined to be the *Phon* [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon ]. There is indeed some relation between intensity and loudness (which is to be expected as, all other things equal, if you increase the intensity more energy will go "into" the auditory system) but it is rather complex and I don't think that it does result to be measured in $\frac{W}{m^{2}}$ since many transductions take place (and more complex reasons).

Answer (score 4):

Your initial point of reasoning is wrong in the strict definition of [loudness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness). The "official" unit of loudness is the [Phon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon).

The whole concept of loudness is a rather complex one since it is actually defined to be the measure of subjective sensation of how loud a sound is perceived to be. The whole system involved in the process is extremely complex comprised of subsystems with many transductions and coding/decoding taking place.

A very brief and abstracted example of the transductions and subsystems involved are the acoustical-to-mechanical transduction system of the middle ear (tympanic membrane and the [ossicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossicles)), then mechanical-to-electrical transduction in the cochlea (with many subsystems involved where "mechanical-to-chemical" and "chemical-to-electrical" transductions taking place) to the nerves where the information is "coded" and then taking place in other "sensorineural information fusion" (for example, visual information affects the perception of loudness and spatialisation of sound). Finally, expectation (related to the long-term memory of the person) plays an important role since it introduces a bias towards your previous expectations.

As you can easily realise, after so many transduction and "fusion of information" it is not trivial (or easy at all) to derive a specific unit in physical quantities for the loudness.

To conclude, you cited the unit of [sound intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity) which is indeed related to loudness in some (very) non-linear frequency (and not only) dependent way. This is, to a certain extend, shown in the [Fletcher-Munson equal-loudness contours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour) from which the Phon is derived (please note that these contours are derived from monofrequency signal experiments). There is a "rough" rule-of-thumb that for a ten-fold increase of intensity (this is an increase of about $10 ~ dB_{ISL}$ (where ISL stands for Intensity Sound Level when $10^{-12} \frac{W}{m^{2}}$ is used as the reference value) results in roughly doubling of loudness.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to view $\frac{W}{m^2}$ is using $W=\frac{N\ m}{s}$  The numerator of that is Newton-meters (aka Joules) which is a measure of energy.  Power (such as watts) is the ability to do work per unit time.

Thinking in those terms, I'd break up your units into $kg\frac{m}{s^2}\frac{1}{s}$.  The middle term is an acceleration, so it can be thought of as the rate ($\frac 1 s$) that one can accelerate ($\frac m {s^2}$) some object with a given mass ($kg$).  I'd be warry of lumping the $\frac 1 s$ and $\frac 1 {s^2}$ into one $\frac 1 {s^3}$ term because intuitively the first term is associated with the rate energy is being added into the system while the second is associated with the change in the accelerated object.  Lumping them into one term obscures this.